# How to get attributes from both relative and absolute positioning

Tags: html, css

I have a footer that i want to attach to the bottom of the page using `bottom:0px`.  However, I also want to center it by using `margin-left:auto;` and `margin-right:auto;`.  Effectively, this will stick the footer to the bottom of the page while keeping it centered vertically.

Unfortunately, these cannot be used together as `bottom:0px` requires `position:relative` while `margin-left:auto` and `margin-right:auto` require `position:absolute`.

How can I get both of these attributes onto the same div without creating a container?

If not possible, what is a clean way of getting both these attributes?

ALSO: I do NOT want to have a fixed position.

footer.css:

```
.footer
{
    /*background-color:blue;*/


    min-height:10px;
    width:940px;


    margin-top:5px;
    margin-left:auto; /* WILL ONLY WORK IF POSITION IS RELATIVE */
    margin-right:auto;
    padding:5px;

    display:block;

    border-top: 3px solid #CCCCCC;

    text-align: center;
    font-family:arial;
    color:gray;

    position: relative;

    bottom:0px; /* WILL ONLY WORK IF POSITION IS ABSOLUTE */
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You want a sticky footer... [Good example](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/). [Google search](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=sticky+footer+html+CSS&oq=sticky+footer+html+CSS&aqs=chrome..69i57.4151j0j9&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @CBroe removing margin-left & margin-right, as well as adding left and right to 0 while changing position to absolute does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a fixed width for your footer, you can use this solution:

```
float:left;
min-height:10px;
width:940px;
position: absolute;
left:50%;
bottom:0px; 
margin-left:-470px;
```

Please see this: http://jsfiddle.net/vY9UJ/

Comment: Easy to implement and works perfectly, thanks very much.

Comment: Nope, does not work perfectly – when the viewport is smaller than 940px, your footer will be partially outside of the visible area, and the left side of it will not be accessible via scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

Change your method of sticking your footer to the bottom.

This example is adapted from [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/)

**Updated with centred div**

Have a fiddle - [Fiddle Link!](http://jsfiddle.net/A3peW/1/)

HTML

```
<div class="page-wrap">

  Content!

</div>

<footer class="site-footer">
  <div id="centered">I'm centered!</div>
</footer>
```

CSS

```
/* From CSS Reset */
html, body, body div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, abbr, address, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp, small, strong, sub, sup, var, b, i, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, figure, footer, header, menu, nav, section, time, mark, audio, video, details, summary {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        vertical-align: baseline;
        background: transparent;
} 
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.page-wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  /* equal to footer height */
  margin-bottom: -142px; 
}
.page-wrap:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}
.site-footer, .page-wrap:after {
  /* .push must be the same height as footer */
  height: 142px; 
}
.site-footer {
  background: orange;
}
#centered {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 550px;
    background: #F00;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have elements with `float="left"` or `float="right"` before the footer. So add empty div with clear="both" just before the footer and set `margin-left:"auto"` and `margin-right:"auto"` to footer.

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
<footer> .... </footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested in a comment before, setting `left` and `right` to `0` will do the trick – your mistake was just that you *removed* the `auto` margins on either side – those are necessary for this to work.

```
.footer {
    min-height:10px;
    width:940px;
    padding:5px;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
    background-color:#ff7575;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vY9UJ/1/

And this doesn’t have the drawback of the `left:50%`, negative-`margin-left` “solution” – if the viewport is to small, the footer content will at least still be accessible via scrollbar.